# Ubuntu 12.10 has 80 Degree Celsius laptop temperature

Tags: 12.10

My laptop seems to be wobbling between 70-85 degrees Celsius. I'm pretty sure this isn't normal, as my laptop is shutting itself off nearly every two hours. PLEASE help.

Inspiron 15R Laptop

I forgot to mention. I do not have this issue AT ALL when I boot with Windows 8.

Comment: Can you add some hardware information please?  Thanks!

Comment: please post result of `lspci | grep VGA`. Most possibly you have dual GPU that is creating this issue.

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Caicos [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]

Comment: Upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04 appears to have fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try taking a can of compressed air and blowing it out.

Comment: Please provide practical and sustainable solutions. People ask questions so that they get a proper solution to their problems not mockery.

Comment: @Jobin This is a practical and sustainable solution. Blowing the dust out of a computer often substantially improves its cooling, as dust is (unfortunately) an excellent insulator, creating many pockets of uncirculating air. I've extended the lives of many computers by doing this, though I usually use a vacuum cleaner with a nozzle-like attachment (and a fresh bag, no need to add dust!). The vacuum cleaner is cheaper (at least if you already have one), doesn't run out, and has no propellants that are toxic and sometimes environmentally harmful. *(But the problem here seems Ubuntu-specific.)*

Comment: @EliahKagan: Your last line is why I down voted and commented.

Comment: @Jobin If the machine runs hotter in Ubuntu than Windows, making it run cooler *all the time* by removing accumulated dust will not likely make it run the same temperature in both OSes--Ubuntu will still run hotter. But it may make it so that Ubuntu runs cool enough that the temperature difference doesn't matter. If you think answers to this question should only address the technical problem in Ubuntu--and I'm not saying that position is unreasonable--your downvote makes sense. But if you thought this post was impractical, unsustainable, mocking, or unhelpful, you may want to reconsider.

Comment: @Everyone: I am extremely sorry if I have been rude here but I just didn't want to spread/encourage what I thought was wrong/incorrect message/answer. I, in no way, wanted to demean or demoralize the answerer for posting his opinion. I, hereby, correct my stance if it had been wrongly taken. Sorry once again :)

Comment: @Jobin I don't think you've been rude. **I do think you were mistaken to say this answer was *mockery***. (Perhaps you thought s/he was saying the OP should blow canned air through the machine constantly to cool it, rather than once to clean it out?) Besides that, I think your opinions have been reasonable. When you think an answer is wrong or unhelpful, the best thing to do is usually to downvote and comment. That's what you've done.